# Pass array in the CodeIgniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass an array in codeigniter query. Below is my code.

Controller

```
 foreach($array as $values) {
    $array_values = $values['download_subcategory_name'];
    }
$this->data['get_downloads_content'] = $this->my_model->get_downloads_content($array_values );
```

Model

```
public function get_downloads_content($array_values ){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('my_table');
        $this->db->where_in('download_subcategory_name', $array_values );
        $this->db->order_by('download_id', 'ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

My problem is query showing results for only last value of array instead of all array values.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need little changes within `foreach`

```
$array_values = array();
foreach($array as $values) {
    $array_values[] = $values['download_subcategory_name'];
                 ^^^
}
```

OR

```
$array_values = array();
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    $array_values[$key] = $values['download_subcategory_name'];
                 ^^^^^^
}
```

Within your code it's storing only the last value from the `foreach` loop thats why it only gets the single value stored within it.